# Why is this Mingw-w64 package so large?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, compiling, packaging, c++

Is it possible to install *only* `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`? I need it for one command and the `mingw-w64` installation is over 800MB... I'm in Debian Buster, but the same is true for other Linux flavors I just tried.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mingw-w64 -V --no-install-recommends
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   binutils-mingw-w64-i686 (2.31.1-11+8.3)
   binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 (2.31.1-11+8.3)
   g++-mingw-w64 (8.3.0-6+21.3~deb10u1)
   g++-mingw-w64-i686 (8.3.0-6+21.3~deb10u1)
   g++-mingw-w64-x86-64 (8.3.0-6+21.3~deb10u1)
   gcc-mingw-w64 (8.3.0-6+21.3~deb10u1)
   gcc-mingw-w64-base (8.3.0-6+21.3~deb10u1)
   gcc-mingw-w64-i686 (8.3.0-6+21.3~deb10u1)
   gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 (8.3.0-6+21.3~deb10u1)
   mingw-w64 (6.0.0-3)
   mingw-w64-common (6.0.0-3)
   mingw-w64-i686-dev (6.0.0-3)
   mingw-w64-x86-64-dev (6.0.0-3)
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 137 MB of archives.
After this operation, 809 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Which command are you after, exactly? (I’m the MinGW-w64 maintainer in Debian and Ubuntu, I’m always interested in use-cases for the packages.)

Answer (score 16):

> Why is this Mingw-w64 package so large?

Because [`mingw-w64`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/mingw-w64) is a meta-package providing the MinGW-w64 toolchain with a C and C++ compiler targeting all supported targets. Currently this involves four different backends (32- and 64-bit, combined with POSIX and Windows threading models).

If you don’t need all that, you can ask `apt` to only install the compiler you’re interested in, and you’ll end up with a smaller set of packages:

```
apt install gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64
```

This will install the 64-bit toolchain, without `g++`. That’s still around 300MiB...

The next version of Debian (and Ubuntu 20.04) provide finer granularity, so you can specify only one of the threading models:

```
apt install gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if you don't need the full suite, you can choose to install a specific part of it.  Installing `gcc-mingw-w64` will give you everything needed by C, but exclude support for C++.  This might be perfect for you.

If you want to bring in less, you could bring in only `gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64` to allow you to compile for x86-64 architectures only.  That will exclude any i686 support. If you are trying to compile with posix-threads only on Debian bullseye and above, you could isolate this further to `gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix`.

Note that even if you go as specific as `gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix`, you'll still get the `*-runtime`, `-base`, `binutils-*` and `*-dev` packages.

If your plan is not to compile, but rather just use something like `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-elfedit`, then you could simply install `binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64`. You can use `apt-file list <package>` to see the files each package provides.

The dependency tree on Debian bullseye (11) and Ubuntu 20.04 looks like this:

```
mingw-w64
 |- gcc-mingw-w64
 |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-i686
 |   |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix
 |   |   |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix-runtime
 |   |   |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-base
 |   |   |   |- binutils-mingw-w64-i686
 |   |   |   `- mingw-w64-i686-dev
 |   |   `- gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32
 |   |       |- gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32-runtime
 |   |       |- gcc-mingw-w64-base
 |   |       |- binutils-mingw-w64-i686
 |   |       `- mingw-w64-i686-dev
 |   `- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64
 |       |- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix
 |       |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix-runtime
 |       |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-base
 |       |   |- binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64
 |       |   `- mingw-w64-x86-64-dev
 |       `- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32
 |           |- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32-runtime
 |           |- gcc-mingw-w64-base
 |           |- binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64
 |           `- mingw-w64-x86-64-dev
 `- g++-mingw-w64
     |- g++-mingw-w64-i686
     |   |- g++-mingw-w64-i686-posix
     |   |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix
     |   |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-i686-posix-runtime
     |   |   `- gcc-mingw-w64-base
     |   `- g++-mingw-w64-i686-win32
     |       |- gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32
     |       |- gcc-mingw-w64-i686-win32-runtime
     |       `- gcc-mingw-w64-base
     `- g++-mingw-w64-x86-64
         |- g++-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix
         |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix
         |   |- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix-runtime
         |   `- gcc-mingw-w64-base
         `- g++-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32
             |- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32
             |- gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32-runtime
             `- gcc-mingw-w64-base
```

Bonus: The maintainer for mingw frequents this site.  You might get a better answer from him.

Answer (score -2):

```
apt download x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
dpkg-deb -R x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc*deb temp
cp temp/your/required/file /tmp/file
rm -rf x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc*
```